# counter example in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a connected open set and let $f: G →\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic
function. Then the following are equivalent statements:
(a) $f=0$;
(b) there is a point $a$ in $G$ such that $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for each $n ≥ 0$;
(c) $\{z ∈ G:f(z)= O\}$ has a limit point in $G$.

Give an example to show that $G$ must be assumed to be connected in Theorem.

This is a problem from conway.can anyone suggest me a proper example. Thank you.

Comment: First, do you have an example of an open set that is not connected?  Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D$ be the open unit disk and $B$ the ball of radius $1/2$ centered at $2$. Define $f: B \cup D \rightarrow \mathbb C$ by $f|_D=0$ and $f|_B=2$.

Comment: the function you give it has no zero.so how can i apply the theorem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit tired. Try it now.